# What does "lightweight extension" stands for? (UML)

Tags: uml

I'm studing UML and while I was reading what a **UML Profile** is, I read

> "Profile is a profile package that extends a reference metamodel (such
>   as UML) by allowing to adapt or customize the metamodel with
>   constructs that are specific to a particular domain, platform, or a
>   software development method. In other words, profile is a **lightweight
>   extension mechanism** to the UML standard."

Source: http://www.uml-diagrams.org/profile.html

I tried to look for the term in Google but I was not able to find anyting.

Thanks in advance.

Andrés-J. Cremades

Answer (score 2):

It would probably best to ask the umldiagrams.org authors what they meant with "lightweight". Actually you can construct quite heavy weight profiles with UML as for example BMPN, SysML, Archimate and others. Their complexity is comparable to UML itself.